# How to set initial filter on a Kendo Grid for ASP.NET

Tags: filter, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I use Kendo Grid for ASP.NET from Telerik to show some data.

Data contains a status that can be filtered. Status contains 3 values; "Draft", "Ready for review" and "Sent".

Initially, I only want to display data with status "Draft" and "Ready for review" - but the user should also be able to view all "Sent" items by changing the filter.

If I set the filter as shown below, the filter dropdown will not display the "Sent" status.

**Index.cshtml**

```cs
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyEntity>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .Columns(columns => {
            columns
                .Bound(e => e.Created)
                .Filterable(false);
            columns
                .Bound(e => e.Subject)
                .Filterable(false);
            columns
                .Bound(e => e.Status)
                .Filterable(f => f.Multi(true));
        })
        .ClientRowTemplate(
            "<tr data-uid='#: uid #'>" +
            "<td class='col-md-2'>#=kendo.toString(Created,'yyyy-MM-dd')#</td>" +
            "<td class='col-md-6'>#: Subject #</td>" +
            "<td class='col-md-2'>#: Status #</td>" +
            "</tr>"
        )
        .NoRecords("No records found!")
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Sort(sort => {
                sort.Add("Created");
                sort.Add("Status").Ascending();
            })
            .Filter(filters => {
                filters
                    .Add(f => f.Status)
                    .IsEqualTo("Draft")
                    .Or()
                    .IsEqualTo("Ready for review");
            })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Controller"))
        )
    )
```

**Controller**

```cs
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        // Get data
        var data = db.Data.Where(n => !n.Deleted.HasValue).ToList();

        // Apply sorting
        IQueryable<Xxx> items = data.AsQueryable();

        // Apply filters
        items = items.ApplyFiltering(request.Filters);

        // Calculate the total number of records
        var total = items.Count();

        // Apply sorting
        items = items.ApplySorting(request.Groups, request.Sorts);

        // Apply paging
        items = items.ApplyPaging(request.Page, request.PageSize);

        // Initialize the DataSourceResult
        var result = new DataSourceResult()
        {
            // Process data (paging and sorting applied)
            Data = items,
            // Total number of records
            Total = total
        };

        // Return the result as JSON
        return Json(result);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> data, IList<IFilterDescriptor> filterDescriptors)
    {
        if (filterDescriptors != null && filterDescriptors.Any())
        {
            data = data.Where(ExpressionBuilder.Expression<T>(filterDescriptors));
        }

        return data;
    }
```

How can I set the default filter, but let the user be able to change the filter (enable other values that are not part of the default filter)

In other words I want the default filter for the Status column (when clicking on the small filter button) to look like the image below.

[image: Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC - Kendo Grid]

Comment: I have \ had a similar issue, however, I tacked this using a kendo dropdownlist and using the change event to get the new data that is sought.  In the way you are doing it currently are you getting all of the data for both statuses and then asking the grid to show you which but actually having it show you all?

Comment: The status dropdown list has to show all three status with only two selected - and the table only showing the two selected status.

Comment: can you show more of your code relating to the grid please.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9gnsj/, this will definitely helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (finally) found this answer, which helped me: https://www.telerik.com/forums/filter-with-multiple-default-values (don't know why my searching didn't find it earlier)

I thought I had tried it... but I must have done something wrong - because this works...